# Plot Command Does Not Show Anything

Tags: matlab

I am new at Matlab and I am trying to plot Y function for every X value. For this, I used below codes. Figure screen opens but there is not anything on the screen.

```
>> X = [0:0.001:0.04]
>> for i=1:40
Y = 6113 * cos(2*pi*200*X(i) + 1508);
end
>> plot(Y,X)
```

And I also tryed this.

```
>> X = [0:0.001:0.04]
>> for i=1:40
Y = 6113 * cos(2*pi*200*X(i) + 1508);
>> plot(Y,X)
end
```

How can I fix this? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first.

JollyRoger answer is correct, however, let us see what you are doing wrong.

You are trying to plot `Y` vs `X`.

```
plot(Y,X)
```

However your `X` is a vector while `Y` is a scalar. Additionally you should invert the command as `X` is your independent variable

```
plot(X,Y)
```

So what can you do to make Y an vector holding information for each `X`-Value? You need to save it for each entry:

```
for k=1:40
Y(k) = 6113 * cos(2*pi*200*X(k) + 1508);
end
```

First of all the variable `Y` is now index and becomes a vector. As you see I changed your index variable to`k` as `i` is also the complex number.

If you would try to plot this `plot(X,Y)`, you would get an error as `X`and `Y` dont have the same length, `X` has more values. So you need to adapt the plot command:

```
plot(X(1:40),Y)
```

If you want `Y` to have the same amount of values as `X` you have to make the for loop as long as your vector `X`,

```
for k=1:length(X)
Y(k) = 6113 * cos(2*pi*200*X(k) + 1508);
end
plot(X,Y)
```

As a final note, try to pre-allocate your variables before using them in a for-loop for improving code execution time. e.g.:

```
Y=zeros(size(X));
for k=1:length(X)
Y(k) = 6113 * cos(2*pi*200*X(k) + 1508);
end
plot(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found how to do this. I tryed the code below and it worked:

```
>> Y = 6113 * cos(2*pi*200*X + 1508);
>> plot(Y,X)
```